# Laravel Component parameters and merging when using a variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, web-component

I know I can add classes to a simple component like this:

```
<x-component class="float-left">Simple example</x-component>
```

which based on the following component:

```
<div {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'alert']) }}>
    {{ $message }}
</div>
```

would result in:

```
<div class="alert float-left">
    Simple example
</div>
```

but how would i do this if my component creates the classes dynamically so I pass a variable called $class into the component so it at it's simplest level would be:

```
<div {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => $class]) }}>
    {{ $message }}
</div>
```

but with above example the float-left class is not added and it only adds what is in the $class variable.

How do I merge whatever is passed as a class into the component with whatever is in the $class variable passed from the php part of the component?
For simplicity assume that the view/component part is this:

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\View\Component;

class Component extends Component
{
    public string $class;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->class  = $this->getClasses();
    }

    public function render(): View
    {
        return view('components.component');
    }


    private function getClasses(): string
    {
        $classes = [];
        $classes[] = 'text-red';
        $classes[] = 'm-4';

        return implode( ' ', $classes );

    }

}
```